# Overloading the operator new in MFC project - C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I tried to overload the operator new in MFC and it didn't compile so i did #undef `new` but it still didn't work due to linker errors such as:

> error LNK2005: "`void * __cdecl operator new(unsigned __int64)`"
>   (??2@YAPEAX_K@Z) already defined in Database SoftwareDlg.obj

and

> fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

```
void* operator new(size_t size)
{
  return malloc(size);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Is your `operator new` definition in a header that's included in multiple translation units?

Comment: @G.M. i think so, if it is, is there a solution?

Comment: The correct fix depends on the details of the code.  For that reason you really should provide a [mcve].

Comment: Re-defining `operator new()` in an MFC project is an exercise in futility. MFC already does (to implement leak detection), using non-conforming preprocessor hacks (that were probably legal at the time MFC started out). Fighting the preprocessor isn't going to be fun. If at all possible, it surely takes a lot of diligence to perform this stunt. Either drop MFC or the idea to overload `operator new()`.

Comment: An overloaded `new` operator needs to be a non-inline function defined in a .cpp file.  And you need to provide a matching `operator delete` function.  Then there are variations for arrays (`operator new[]`, `operator delete[]`), and variations for alignment and/or nothrow.  And the Microsoft Debug library has its own versions for tracking memory leaks.

Comment: In general, put the declaration `void* foo();` in a common *.h file. Then put the definition `void* foo(){...}` in one *.cpp file. But as noted earlier, there is no good reason to redefine `new` in MFC